# Keep on getting error while trying to upload to esp32-cam

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I just got my new esp32-cam and I keeps giving me the error below even though i did everything in the tutorial video I found on youtube correctly and even watched several others and it still gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "esptool.py", line 3682, in <module>
  File "esptool.py", line 3675, in _main
  File "esptool.py", line 3329, in main
  File "esptool.py", line 263, in __init__
  File "site-packages\serial\__init__.py", line 88, in serial_for_url
  File "site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 78, in open
  File "site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 222, in _reconfigure_port
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: WindowsError(31, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.')
Failed to execute script esptool
the selected serial port Failed to execute script esptool
 does not exist or your board is not connected
```

Comment: Check the driver for the virtual serial port.

Comment: it works now but keeps looping

Comment: Brownout detector was triggered ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57 rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT) configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00 mode:DIO, clock div:2 load:0x3fff0018,len:4 load:0x3fff001c,len:1216 ho 0 tail 12 room 4 load:0x40078000,len:10944 load:0x40080400,len:6360 entry 0x400806b4

Comment: Looks like your power supply doesn't deliver enough power